# bundler's executable "bundle" conflicts with /usr/local/bin/bundle Overwrite the executable?

Tags: ruby, jekyll

When I install jekyll bundle and entering the command of `gem install jekyll bundler`.
The terminal pop up the message of bundler's executable "bundle" conflicts with /usr/local/bin/bundle

Overwrite the executable?

Comment: the conflict means you already have `Bundler` installed.. You can try proceeding with `gem install jekyll`

Comment: Thanks a lot!! Got it.

Answer (score 5):

In my case, I have to overwrite both `/usr/local/bin/bundle`  and `/usr/local/bin/bundler` in order to successfully installed bundler-1.16.6. Otherwise, when running `jekyll new websitedir`, an error with the following message occurs.

> Bundler: ruby: No such file or directory -- /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.16.1/exe/bundle (LoadError)

In most cases, I think it is safe to overwrite. But it is always good to check what you are actually overwriting. For example, running `ls -alh /usr/local/bin/bundle` in the terminal gives us the following output. Thus, it is safe to overwrite.

> /usr/local/bin/bundle -> ../Cellar/ruby/2.5.1/libexec/gembin/bundle

Answer (score 1):

This answer is not related to Jekyll, but I'm adding it here because I got a similar error when I ran  `> gem install bundler` .

Message I saw: bundler's executable "bundle" conflicts with C:/Ruby25-x64/bin/bundle
Overwrite the executable? (I chose 'n'.)

As ashmaroli wrote above, **the conflict meant I already had Bundler installed**.

**How to check if Bundler is installed:** 
 `> bundler --version`

If it returns a version, it's installed. Bundler version 1.17.3 is what I get when I run that command.

**The action I took:** I chose not to overwrite the executable. I just needed Bundler installed and didn't realize that it was already.